# Finding the integral over a given path.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We need to calculate : $$\int_C(5xydx + 10yzdy + zdz)$$

where $C$ is an arc $ x = y^{2}$ from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,0)$ followed by the line segment given by $x=1$ , $y=1$ ,$0\leq z \leq 1$.

(1) For the arc we consider the transformation as $x=t$ , $y = t^{2}$ where $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

So ,the value of the integral comes out to be $ \dfrac{5}{4}$. (   $ \int_0^1 5 t^{3}dt$   )

(2) For the line segment from $(1,1,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$ { $x=1$ , $y=1$ , $0\leq z \leq 1$ } ,

I consider the parametric equation $z = t$ , $x$ and $y$ are constants so $dy$ and $dx$ are zero. So , the integral comes out to be $ \dfrac{1}{2}$. (   $ \int_0^1  tdt$   ) .

So the solution comes out to be $ \dfrac{5}{4} + \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{7}{4}$ , but the solution key says $ \dfrac{5}{2}$ , Am I doing something wrong ? Could anyone tell ?

Comment: For (1) do you mean $x=t^2$, $y=t$?

Comment: Actually $x = t$ , $y = t^{2}$ , just made an edit..

Anyways ,  the answer remains the same..

Comment: If $x=t$, $y=t^2$, then $x=y^2$ does not hold. With the change I proposed, the result changes because now $dx \neq dt$.